# Why won't this simple ruby method run on my local environment?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run the following simple method in my local environment, and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it

```
def test_counter(max)
  i = 0
    count = 0

    while count < max 
      if i != 0
        count = i**2
        i++
      end
    end

puts i
end


test_counter 50
```

I get these errors:

```
practice.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
practice.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: what @JonahR said. Also, you have `i=0` set and `if i != 0` will be false and control would never go inside if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `i++` in ruby; use `i += 1`. Also `i` will never equal something beside 0 so  `if i != 0` does not work